# "VSCODE" - How to change function tag color? -

Tags: visual-studio-code, colors, themes

I would like to do update Monokai template to [“lazy eye”](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/lazy-eye/symptoms-causes/syc-20352391) syndrome. To do it I need to change a few tag colors. One is function but when I add to setting.json

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": "entity.name.function",
          "settings": { "fontStyle": "", "foreground": "#000000" }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

I’m getting the message `Property textMateRules is not allowed.`
How can I change it?
I’m on a mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the setting needed to change is `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"`